# Simple R Function, What Is Wrong?

Tags: r

My code is below, I don't get the issue with my code. I want to return the ggplot  object, but I get unexpected error at the "return" line, and if I delete that one I get unexpected error at the } symbol.

What is wrong?

```
pgraf <- function () {

  library(ggplot2)
  library(gcookbook)

  p <- ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(Date, Weight, fill = Cultivar) + 
                geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack", color = "black") + 
                geom_text(aes(label=Weight) , vjust=0.1)

  return (p)

}
```

Comment: there is a closing bracket missing after `Cultivar)`

Comment: Thank you! Still R executed the code? The error said on the line where the "return (p)" statement is, this is common for R ?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to step through code line by line within R?

Comment: Check out `?debug`. Also, in general it makes for more readable code if you load the libraries you'll be using at the start of the script rather than in the body of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket in the first line of the ggplot call..

```
p <- ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(Date, Weight, fill = Cultivar)**)** +
```

Give that a shot.